# How to make C++ code draw on Java components

Tags: java, c++, user-interface, swing, interop

We are designing physics app, and we would like to have it written in Java, and also we want to use [root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROOT) (root is writen in C++). Root has some nice graphical features -- it is able to draw very nice 3D charts, and I'm thinking whether it's possible to embedd those charts in Java app.

Is there any way to make C++ code draw on for example `JPanel`?

Is there a way to pass back mouse/keyboard events? - we would like to have some interactivity, like rotating a 3d chart.

I asked similar question about embedding a lot of C++ code (that is not related to drawing anything) in Java app (also about root) [it's here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534734/).

Comment: I'll leave this as a comment, but your C++ code could always produce an image buffer or something and then you could simply blt that to your JPanel.

Comment: Thats the first thing I thought about. But: i think that it mat look ugly (if there will be any scaling), and we will not get any interactivity.

Comment: Maybe if you look at the java native api (jni) you can find something usefull.

Comment: Yeah, it's not the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SWT is built to be a fairly thin wrapper around native widgets, it may be easier to work with than Swing/AWT for your particular task. I realize [this particular link](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget/Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget.htm) is a bit old, but it does show how to quickly wrap a native widget.

Answer (score 1):

The JNI comment on the question itself seems to be the best way forward - I don't think you want to draw with root as-is; you'll want to write some interface code in between which is called from Java via JNI, which asks 'root' to redraw its image at a given size (the appropriate size for the image being something only the java component would know). Pass it back to the java component from the JNI call as just 32-bit image data, for instance.

I would not assume you can draw into a java component even in AWT; as it's basically java wrappers around native components - where the drawing is usually done in the native component itself (by the operating system, not by the java code).